# Shared calendars: Gmail, Outlook, Palm pre

Tags: synchronization, gmail, calendar

After googling for a few hours now, I thought of asking for help here. I'd like to achieve the following setup with some friends:

- One shared calendar that everyone *in the group* can modify and access.
- Possibility for each member to sync this calendar with a local Outlook calendar.
- Solutions that can sync to mobile phones score bonus points
- Should be free

Here are the solutions I've tried, and why they didn't work:

- Exchange: We don't have exchange.
- Gmail calendars: very powerful and flexible, but they can't sync to outlook (Gmail Calendar sync only syncs your main calendar)
- Windows live calendars: Outlook connector has lots of bugs.

Could you maybe suggest a solution, preferably a simple one?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen several people do this with Google Calendar -- don't use Gmail Calendar Sync, use gsyncit.

Comment: The problem is, gsyncit is not free

Comment: Correct; it's not free, but it is relatively inexpensive. This is the only "simple" way that I know of making this work.

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping to find a free solution...